# filter ARRAY of ARRAY of STRINGS on unique element

Tags: arrays, swift4, higher-order-functions

I'm trying to extract an album list from an iTunes playlist export.

The **file has a list of all songs in each album**, and I want **just 1 entry per album**, discarding the song titles.

So, I need to **filter on unique album titles**.

I can do this with a loop, deleting duplicate elements until the album count == 1.

But was wondering if there's a more elegant way to achieve this through higher-order functions?

Here's the 2D songs array:

```
var songs[[String]]
```

And structure of inner array:

```
artist, album, song, ...
```

Album, song track array example:

```
["Beck", "Odelay", "Lord Only Knows"]
["Beck", "Odelay", "Hotwax"]
["Beck", "Odelay", "Derelict"]
```

After processing, there should be just a single entry for "Odelay":

```
["Beck", "Odelay", "Lord Only Knows"]
```

And here, the song name is irrelevant, as it will be discarded once I get it into an Excel spreadsheet.

**ADDITION (2.15):**

So here's an iterative way to achieve my goal.

```
    var songs = [[""]]
    var uniqueAlbums = [[""]]

    <code to load songs array here>


    // grab list of unique album titles
    let albumTitles = (Set(songs.map { $0[2] })).sorted()

    var cnt = 0
    for title in albumTitles {

        // grab all songs for this album
        let currentAlbum = songs.filter { $0[2] == title }

        // loop thru songs till last song, then add only one entry per album to new array
        for album in currentAlbum {
            if cnt < currentAlbum.count - 1 {
                cnt += 1
            } else {
                uniqueAlbums.append(album)
            }
        }
        cnt = 0
    }

// uniqueAlbums[] is now a filtered collection of songs[] with only 1 album per line
```

It would be neat if there was SQL-like syntax for 2D arrays built into swift, as it's trivial to write SQL code to accomplish this:

```
SELECT artist, DISTINCT album FROM songs ORDER BY album
```

Or using array subscripts:

```
SELECT songs[0], DISTINCT songs[1] FROM songs ORDER BY songs[1]
```

Comment: After processing, your result should be 2D array  or normal array without any duplicate entry ?

Comment: 2D array without duplicate album titles.

Answer (score 0):

Here is to get unique array data from 2D array

```
let uniueSongs = Array(Set(songs.flatMap{$0}))
```

Comment: This creates a 1D array

Answer (score 0):

Use this to remove duplicates from your 2D array, and receive response as 2D array with unique values:

```
let tempSongs = songs.map({Array(Set($0))})
```

Comment: This code creates a duplicate of the original array.